# PyQt QGridLayout remove all but top row

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a QGridLayout of which during the program run, rows get added (containing some labels and a delete button)

The first row is a title row.

When in my program someone clicks new I would like to remove all but the top row of this QGridLayout.

I have searched the internet but all I can find is removeWidget which does not remove the row (or reset the rowcount) preferably I delete the rows so only the top row is left.

Is this at all possible? If not what is the simpler workaround?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that might help some. That is why I am posting it here:

As far as I understood from googling it is never possible to remove a row from a QGridLayout.

My QGridlaout was in another grid. So I chose to do:

```
grid.removeWidget(toberemovedgrid)
sip.delete(toberemovedgrid)
toberemovedgrid = None
newgrid = QGridLayout()
grid.addWidget(newgrid)
```

It is not really an answer to my question but it might help someone